# host github page shows 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github

I have a create-react-app application and I pushed it on a repository at github
My next step is to make it visible to all using github pages

I've created a branch called gh-pages, and finally I obtain this link from github:
https://jotasenator.github.io/blogjotas/

but when I search for this adress my 404 page shows up and then I can click on home, contact links etc...
what is happening..

of course, at https://github.com/jotasenator/blogjotas/blob/main/src/App.js none of my adresses configuration contains blogjotas...

should i change it  to

or what?

should I run a build and push it ?

fell free to try this page to see my 404 error page instead of the main page

thank for the help, it feels so close to publish my first web app!

Comment: this: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages

Comment: Was an internal problem of my own app. i just re configurate the path='/' to path='/blogjotas/...